# Simulate ListView wrap_content behavior up to specific height in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

My Activity consists of two parts: 1) A listview at the top. 2) The bottom part (which for simplicity is just a TextView with a black background).
I want the black TextView to be placed right after the last element of the ListView. I can easily achieve this by setting the height of the ListView to wrap_content (please don't tell me that I shouldn't use wrap_content for ListView's height):
[image]

Here's where the problem begins: I don't want the ListView to grow more than half a screen (when there are a lot of items in the ListView I want it to behave as if it was a normal ListView (scrollable) that only takes up half of the Activity screen, like here:
[image]

**Is it possible to do this by just manipulating XML? If yes - how? If not - can you, please, point me to the relevant direction of how to achieve this in code?**

Comment: You want the sizes of the ListView and the TextView as half the screen?

Comment: No, I do not want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of behavior is too dynamic to define in XML, but it's easy enough to accomplish with a custom container view.  I'm making a couple of assumptions about your application, primarily that the root layout of the Activity only has two children (the `ListView` and the footer view).  Based on that, the following is a custom `LinearLayout` which will give you what you need:

```
public class ComboLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public ComboLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ComboLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //We're cheating a bit here, letting the framework measure us first
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        //Impose a maximum height on the first child
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        int newHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredHeight() / 2, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        if (child.getMeasuredHeight() > (getMeasuredHeight() / 2)) {
            measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, newHeightSpec);
        }

        //Optional, make the second child always half our height
        child = getChildAt(1);
        measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, newHeightSpec);
    }
}
```

Then you can apply this in your Activity layout like so:

```
<com.example.myapplication.ComboLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hi Mom!"
        android:background="#0A0"/>
</com.example.myapplication.ComboLinearLayout>
```

The net effect of the container code is that it fixes the measured height of the `ListView` to exactly half the container height if and only if it measures itself larger than that.  Otherwise, it allows the `ListView` to be smaller.

There's a secondary trick I added in case you needed it, which is an optional block of code that forces the footer view to always be half the screen height.  If you are setting the footer view to a fixed height in XML, you can probably remove that second section from `onMeasure()`.  If you use that code, it will work best if the footer view is set to `match_parent` in XML.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this brilliant effort. I'll accept your answer soon, I want to wait a bit if someone else wants to pitch in.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible only using xml. If you set the fixed height or weight of the ListView, it will always take the fixed position. To achieve this you will have to set listview parent height dynamically as listview grows and stop it when it meets your requirement. Hope it will help you.